# Stuff query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores multiple values for same ID. The table looks like below:

[image]

I want to concatenate values with '&' separated.

Desired output:

[image]

My query is not producing desired output. Below is my query:

```
create table #temp (cid int, val1 int, val2 int, val3 int, val4 int)
  insert #temp values
    (1001,10,11,15,19),
    (1002,15,Null,16,18),
    (1003,14,18,15,NULL)

SELECT distinct t2.cid,
        STUFF(( SELECT '&' + REPLACE(t1.val1,'.','') +
                             REPLACE(t1.val2,'.','') +
                             REPLACE(t1.val3,'.','') + 
                             REPLACE(t1.val4,'.','')
                FROM #temp t1
                WHERE t1.cid = t2.cid
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 1, 1,'') as 'output'
        FROM #temp t2
```

Note: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: what output is it returning?

Comment: I am using 2014 version

Comment: @Rick, was your question answered? If so, consider to mark it as such one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `concat_ws()` functionality.  You can do this in SQL Server as:

```
select t.cid,
       stuff( (coalesce('&' + t.val1, '') +
               coalesce('&' + t.val2, '') +
               coalesce('&' + t.val3, '') +
               coalesce('&' + t.val4, '')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as vals               
from #temp t;
```

This is the most convenient equivalent to `concat_ws()` that I've found in SQL Server.

If the values are integers, just cast them:

```
select t.cid,
       stuff( (coalesce('&' + cast(t.val1 as varchar(255)), '') +
               coalesce('&' + cast(t.val2 as varchar(255)), '') +
               coalesce('&' + cast(t.val3 as varchar(255)), '') +
               coalesce('&' + cast(t.val4 as varchar(255)), '')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as vals               
from #temp t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44934027d55497437d2a51fd4785751b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: You forgot that val1 and the rest are integers, so you need to cast them before adding them to '&'

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you have a reason to use COALESCE over ISNULL?? for me ISNULL is better

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2017 you can use CONCAT_WS (complements to @Joakim Danielson):

```
SELECT cid, CONCAT_WS('&', val1, val2, val3, val4)
FROM #temp
```

For SQL Server 2012 you can use CONCAT:

```
SELECT cid, CONCAT(val1, '&', val2, '&', val3, '&', val4)
FROM #temp
```

For all Versions of SQL Server you can use the '+' to concatenate.

```
SELECT cid, val1 + '&' + val2 + '&' + val3 + '&' + val4
FROM #temp
```

Given that your example includes NULL and appears to be storing integers, I would recommend the following:

```
SELECT  cid
       ,STUFF(COALESCE( '&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, val1), '')
             + COALESCE( '&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, val2), '')
             + COALESCE( '&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, val3), '')
             + COALESCE('&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, val4), ''), 1, 1, '')
FROM #temp
```

*Accepted edit to include STUFF to remove the trailing '&'

The COALESCE() will have the effect of not including NULL values in your listing, while the CONVERT to varchar will handle the Integers

Comment: Mathew, thanks for the suggestion. I do not want to show extra '&' at the end of each line that is if last value is missing I don't want to end with '&'

Comment: @Rick As you mentioned that you are using SQL 2014 you can use TRIM('&' FROM value)

Comment: I made a change to the last option presented to remove the extra '&'. That will work with older versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @Mathew do you have a reason to use COALESCE over ISNULL?? For me ISNULL is better

Comment: Non of your suggested solutions work properly except the first one and that is for the wrong version as we both know.

Comment: @DanielBrughera, I tend to use COALESCE because it's ANSI standard SQL, while ISNULL is specific to SQL Server.  Unless the slight performance difference is relevant or I am using it in cases where the nullability of the result is relevant I tend to use COALESCE.

Comment: I have been asking for that in other questions and i never get an answer, I didn't know that is ANSI stardard. Tank you... Anyway since the question is tagged as sql-server and the nullability is irrelevant here, I still prefer ISNULL ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use CONCAT_WS for this

```
SELECT cid, CONCAT_WS('&', val1, val2, val3, val4)
FROM #temp
```

Comment: this assumes SQL Server 2017

Comment: I am using 2014 version

Answer (score 1):

> I have a table that stores multiple values for same ID.

If CID values are not unique:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t2.cid,
       REPLACE(STUFF(
       (
           SELECT '|' + CAST(val AS VARCHAR(50))
           FROM
           (
               SELECT cid,   val1 AS val  FROM #temp     
               UNION ALL
               SELECT cid,  val2 AS val   FROM #temp
               UNION ALL
               SELECT cid,  val3 AS val   FROM #temp
               UNION ALL
               SELECT cid,  val4 AS val   FROM #temp
           ) t1
           WHERE t1.cid = t2.cid
                 AND t1.val IS NOT NULL
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),    1, 1, ''), '|', '&') AS 'output'
FROM #temp t2;
```

Results to:

```
cid     output
1001    10&11&15&19
1002    15&16&18
1003    14&18&15
```

Otherwise, `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` as other members correctly suggested  is more elegant solution